# BM-800 Microphone sound quality problem

Tags: microphone

I just got a 6 dollar sound card, now I connect my microphone (BM-800) to the sound card and then I connect the sound card to my laptop. It works but the quality of the audio is just terrible. What am I possibly doing wrong

Comment: My fellow members; Just a reminder to please try to be nice, especially to new users who may also be new to the field and be struggling to find help. Thanks fam!

Comment: Can you please describe the quality of the sound? (Edit your question.)

Comment: @philburns - what happens with these mics when you try power them from a computer's built-in headset power supply is pretty well known. It's really a bad case of false advertising that these will work like a headset mic using the tiny voltage a computer can provide [& the stupid TRS cable they supply]. They really won't. They need 48v phantom. Once wired like a 'pro mic' with phantom and any budget XLR mic preamp, they're actually not too terrible. [I bought one just to see what they're like & to be able to answer the myriad questions we get about them. Set up properly, they work OK.]